# Can not fix firebase security rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a simple app, where a user A can send notifications (chat, like, comments) to another user B, and obviously, user B can receive and read these notifications.

My firestore database collection looks like this:

```
/Notifications/{userId}/NotificationItems/{notificationId}
```

Where `Notifications` and `NotificationItems` are collections, `userId` is the if of the user who receives the notifications. `notificationId` is a doc, which contains info about the notification.

My collections structure seems reasonable for me, so initially my firestore rule were something like this:

```
match /Notifications/{userId}{
      match /NotificationItems/{notificationId} {
         allow create: if isUserAuthenticated();
         allow read: if isUserAuthenticated() && userOwnsResource(userId);
         allow update: if isUserAuthenticated() && userOwnsResource(userId);
      }
    }
```

Where the functions `userAuthenticated` and `userOwnsResource` are the following:

```
function isUserAuthenticated() {
      return request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    function userOwnsResource(userId) {
      return request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
```

Those functions are good enough, and I can fetch notifications, send them, matk them as seen, etc.

The problem is if I want to send `chat` notification type. If I want to send a chat notification, first, I want to check if I have sent a chat notification sometime before. If I have sent chat notification too soon, I don't send a new one. The firestore call which I make:

```
await firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("Notifications")
    .doc(userId)      //I dont have access to this user notifications as per the above rules
    .collection("NotificationItems")
    .where("chatId", "==", chatId)
    .orderBy("date", "desc")
    .get()
```

And obviously, this call fails. I thought of fixing it by implementing some functions like:

```
function itIsChatNotification(){
                let chatId =  get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Notifications/$(userId)/NotificationItems/$(notificationId)).data.chatId;
            return request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Chats/$(chatId)).data.users;
         }
```

i.e. check if it is a chat notification type, get chatId of this notification, and then check if the user ID belongs to the users who created this chat.

and then change my `read` access to `allow read: if isUserAuthenticated() && (userOwnsResource(userId) || itIsChatNotification());`

Needless to say, the above function did not work, I dont know why.

My chat notification type has fields of `authorId`, `body`, `type` (which is equal to `chat`), `chatId` and `date`.

If anyone can help with writing correct firestore rules, that would be grant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   match /Notifications/{userId}{
  match /NotificationItems/{notificationId} {
    allow create: if isUserAuthenticated();
    allow read: if isUserAuthenticated() && (userOwnsResource(userId) || itIsChatNotification());
    allow update: if isUserAuthenticated() && userOwnsResource(userId);
  }
}

function isUserAuthenticated() {
  return request.auth.uid != null;
}

function userOwnsResource(userId) {
  return request.auth.uid == userId;
}

function itIsChatNotification() {
  let chatId = resource.data.chatId;
  let chatRef = /databases/$(database)/documents/Chats/$(chatId);
  let chatDoc = get(chatRef).data;
  return request.auth.uid in chatDoc.users;
}
```